# Vue3 + Vite + Vuestic: Running in Dev Server but Blank White Page in Production after Making Build

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, vuestic

I created a pdf generator application using vue3, vite and vuestic UI.
Other than these many pdf related npm packages are used.
All can be seen below `package.json` file.

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "receipt-generator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview --port 4173",
    "test:unit": "vitest --environment jsdom",
    "test:e2e": "start-server-and-test preview http://localhost:4173/ 'cypress open --e2e'",
    "test:e2e:ci": "start-server-and-test preview http://localhost:4173/ 'cypress run --e2e'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "maska": "^1.5.0",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "mitt": "^3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "msplit": "^0.1.24",
    "pdfjs": "^2.4.7",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^3.0.279",
    "pinia": "^2.0.21",
    "print-js": "^1.6.0",
    "simple-vue-camera": "^1.1.2",
    "splitpanes": "^3.1.5",
    "vite-plugin-require": "^1.0.5",
    "vue": "^3.2.38",
    "vue-camera-lib": "^1.0.3",
    "vue-multipane": "^0.9.5",
    "vue-pdf": "^4.3.0",
    "vue-resize-split-pane": "^0.1.5",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.5",
    "vue-the-mask": "^0.11.1",
    "vue-web-cam": "^1.9.0",
    "vuestic-ui": "^1.4.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/splitpanes": "^2.2.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.0.3",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx": "^2.0.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.2",
    "cypress": "^10.7.0",
    "jsdom": "^20.0.0",
    "start-server-and-test": "^1.14.0",
    "vite": "^3.0.9",
    "vitest": "^0.23.0"
  }
}
```

## vite.config.js

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url';

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    hunkSizeWarningLimit: '2048 KiB',
  },
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
  define: {
    'process.env': {},
  },
  server: { host: true },
  base: '',
});
```

## Console Errors

A console error mainly related to some incompatibility issue between `jspdf` npm package and `vite`.

```
console.js:22 jsPDF PubSub Error Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded. DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.
    at http://localhost:5174/node_modules/.vite/deps/jspdf.js?v=c100f81e:8314:55
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:5174/node_modules/.vite/deps/jspdf.js?v=c100f81e:8315:8)
    at C.publish (http://localhost:5174/node_modules/.vite/deps/jspdf.js?v=c100f81e:1280:17)
    at Object.Pe (http://localhost:5174/node_modules/.vite/deps/jspdf.js?v=c100f81e:1852:16)
    at E.y2.addFont (http://localhost:5174/node_modules/.vite/deps/jspdf.js?v=c100f81e:2421:179)
    at generatePdf (http://localhost:5174/src/components/PdfView.vue:98:7)
    at http://localhost:5174/src/components/PdfView.vue:1081:3
    at http://localhost:5174/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-AO42RC3Y.js?v=c100f81e:5637:154
    at callWithErrorHandling (http://localhost:5174/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-AO42RC3Y.js?v=c100f81e:156:18)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (http://localhost:5174/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-AO42RC3Y.js?v=c100f81e:164:17)
```

## Production Warnings

```
▲ [WARNING] Expected ";" [css-syntax-error]

    <stdin>:140:24:
      140 │ @apply px-2 py-2 sm:py-0
          │                         ^
          ╵                         ;
```

```
(!) Some chunks are larger than 500 KiB after minification. Consider:
- Using dynamic import() to code-split the application
- Use build.rollupOptions.output.manualChunks to improve chunking: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputmanualchunks
- Adjust chunk size limit for this warning via build.chunkSizeWarningLimit.
```

## Inspection Analysis

Looks like basically, the app is not adding the html inside the `<body>`'s root element `<div id=app">`. See the blank comment `<!---->` inside it below:

```
<div id="app" data-v-app="">
  <!---->
</div>
```

## What I have done so far?

I found on stack overflow that this may be because of the static paths in production by `vite`. But, this problem I solved by adding the line `base: ''` in `vite.config.js`.

**NOTE: The build inside `dist` folder DOESN'T give any errors.**

## FRUSTRATION

It's so frustrating that everything works perfectly in development and I invested almost two complete full-time weeks in development and now it looks like that all went in vain. The client is asking to deploy and I am stuck.

NEED FOR HELP.

Comment: Hello, were you able to fix your error?

Comment: @apply px-2 py-2 sm:py-0; forthe warning just put a semicolon at the end of the affected line. for the atob error you'll need to track down the code that implements jspdf and the data it's trying to process then post that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. My app would work fine in the dev server but would either be blank or some components would not load. The best part was that I got no error messages in the console.

In the end, I figured out that my issue was with Vue Router. In `createRouter()`, try changing your history property to:

```js
history: createWebHashHistory(),
```

The default value `createWebHistory()` does not seem to work out of the box.